# Duplicated edges with the same @rid in OrientDB

Tags: sql, graph, orientdb, graph-databases

I've discovered a strange behaviour when querying an Edge class using OrientDB (community-2.1-rc5). The database is returning the exact same edge with the exact same @rid and the exact same data, **twice**. My instinct says that this is a bug...

This is the query

```
SELECT FROM E WHERE @class='LIKES' AND (out IN [#12:0,#12:221]) AND in=#36:1913
```

And this is what orientDB studio returns

http://s29.postimg.org/hwruv0zif/Captura.png

This makes no sense. If I go to the vertex and query for LIKES relationship it only returns one registry... Anyone faced a problem like this?

This is the database I'm using if it helps

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pkm28cfer1pwpqb/AAAVGeL1eftOGR4o0todTiAha?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get help with this bug, you should make a request to join the google group. StackOverflow is not the best place to get help with this kind of bug.

The problem is that you somehow duplicated your edge by mistake. Orientdb let you do it for some unknown reason.

Here is the bug discussion on the orientdb google group : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/cAR7yUjCZcI

In the discussion Luca(creator of orientdb) says this :

```
"the problem is that without a transaction the creation of edge could
be dirty. OrientDB tries to fix dirty reference, so maybe that's the 
reason why the next time the exception is raised. I've changed the   
default behavior of all SQL commands against Graphs to be always 
transactional"
```

Upgrading to the most recent version of orientdb would be good ideal. Maybe the bug has been fixed.

Comment: I'll start using transactions right the way. Do you recomend separate transactions for Vertices and Edges insertion? Or just one transaction, inserting vertices in the first place and the edges the last. Thank you for everything

Comment: Here there is the documentation for transactions in the graph api : http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#transactions

Comment: But, like Luc said the default behavior of all SQL commands againts Graphs should be always transactional

Comment: Hi, according to Luca since orientdb 2.0 every sql command runs in a transactional way, so this should not have happened. Anyway, I'm rewritting the code to explicitly create a transaction before vertex & edge creation but this is going to destroy the performance since I'm doing massive insertions, and non-tx ops exists precisely to speed up massive insertions (on a single thread application)

Comment: I've just tried your database against develop branch and it seems to work fine...

Comment: I tried this issue several times with the same result (duplicated edge on community 2.1-rc5), maybe it's been solved in the develop brach, don't know... Just in case, now I'm using transactions with upserts, so performance has not been damaged so badly as I thought